# Plugin Local Notification Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, plugins, notifications

This is my code about my notification:

```
var notification = new NotificationRequest
        {
            NotificationId = 100,
            Title = "Test",
            Description = "Test Description",
            CategoryType = NotificationCategoryType.Status,
            Schedule =
            {
                 RepeatType = NotificationRepeat.Daily,
                 NotifyTime = alarmTime
            },
            Android =
            {
                Priority = Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidPriority.Max,
                VisibilityType =   Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidVisibilityType.Public,
            },
            Sound = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "sound" : "sound.mp3",
        };

await LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
```

It is some way to show this notification like popup and the second question its about to show notification when app is closed (killed)

Comment: if your app is not running there is no way it can generate a local notification